# How to use CSRF token in jinja2?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, jinja2

My form.html:

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}">
    <table>
    <tr><p><td>Subject: </td><td><input type="text" name="subject" value="{{ subject }}"></p></td></tr>
    <tr><p><td>Your e-mail (optional): </td><td><input type="text" name="email" value="{{ email }}"></p></td></tr>
    <tr><p><td>Message: </td><td><textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="50">**{{ message }}**</textarea></p></td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

But still i get Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

How to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but I believe {{ csrf_token }} goes on the inside of your form tag.

```
<form>{{ csrf_token }}
blah: <input type="text">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `<meta name="csrf-token" content="[your-token]">`would be better if you use turbo frame https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/frames

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add `django.core.context_processors.csrf` to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting. Otherwise `{{ csrf_token }}` won't have a value.

You're now probably submitting the form with an empty CSRF token.

Comment: I have already added django.core.context_processors.csrf to my TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS. But still i get this error...